# JMETER - 2.13 - Parametrize Post Body Data using CSV Data File

Tags: rest, csv, jmeter

I am trying to do a performance test with a REST Webservice. I added a HTTP Request, Header Manager, HTTP Request defaults, View Results Tree, CSV data config file.

This is how i parametrized my Post Message

```
{  "groupList": [    {"group":"newgroup"}  ],  "user": "${user}",  
"password": "test",  "email": "test@go2group.com",  "role": "USER",  "ui": false}
```

This is my CSV Data Set Config

The Problem i face is `"<EOF>"` is getting added instead of the values.

POST http://cawin.go2group.com/ConnectAll/rest/useradmin/user

POST data:

```
    {  "groupList": [    {"group":"newgroup"}  ],  "user": "<EOF>", 
 "password": "test",  "email": "test@go2group.com",  "role": "USER",  "ui": false}
```

kindly excuse me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

The most common problems are:

1. Using incorrect relative path to CSV file
2. Using incorrect value of "Recycle on EOF" dropdown
3. Incorrect placement of CSV Data Set Config element (sampler out of its scope)

In the majority of cases the answer is in either *jmeter.log* file or in [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) / [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) for detailed end-to-end instructions. If you still experience problems please update your question with first few lines of CSV file and Test Plan screenshot showing CSV Data Set Config location and configuration.